# I can't get 2 references to the same class/table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

i have the following problem:

I have 2 classes that i wan't to use with code first to generate a database.

```
public class Chart
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public State Initial { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class State
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also want the Initial property of the Chart class to point to it's initial State.

But whatever i try i won't get it to work. I've used the data annotations, fluent api and foreignkey properties but keep running into problems like:

"Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."

To make this even more interessting i would also like the initial state to be one of the states of the chart class.

Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE:**

I found a piece of the puzzle:

The code first framework tries to create 2 tables.
Charts: with columns -> Id, Initial_Id
States: with columns -> Id, Name, Chart_Id

Chart.Initial_Id references to the States table and State.Chart_Id references to the Charts table. Now this introduces the circular problem when cascading deleting or insert etc...

Hmmm...

Comment: I have found the following solution:  I will make the charts initial optional. Then i will save the chart, set the initial state and save again. It's ugly, i know, but this way I get the job done.  A layer will hide this uglyness. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but do you think it has something to do with the fact that the properties for both classes (presumably, what you want for your primary key) has a guid called id? What about renaming it to StateId and ChartId? If nothing else, I think this is just better naming practice...

*Full disclosure: I don't use CF EF, but just stumbled across this as an interesting post*

Comment: Thank you for you're suggestion, but i think that's not the problem. The id properties will be the column names for 2 different tables. And I think that it is bad naming practice because the id property is just a property for 2 different classes. Putting the class name before the property name won't add any value to it, simply because it is the property of that specific class. Just like changing the 'name' property to StateName won't add any value to it. It's simply redundant.

Comment: Maybe, but if these are being translated directly into tables, tables that I may be referencing in a context outside of auto-generated queries, I really like being able to see the verbose meaning of the id. 

(Ex: SELECT SomeObjectId
    FROM SomeObject so JOIN SomeOtherObject soo ON so.SomeObjectId = soo.SomeOtherObjectId)

Sorry my thought didn't help the matter at hand, though ;)

Comment: I see where you are going. But i think it is possible to prefix a table name for each column to solve that problem. Right?

Answer (score 0):

EF can't currently perform this mapping exactly as you have it written because it ends up with a combination of circular dependencies and database-generated keys for which update/insert orderings cannot be determined.

However, reading between the lines I'll make the assumption that maybe State entities are supposed to be shared between multiple Chart entities. In other words, multiple Charts can refer to the same State. In this case, what you really have is a many-to-many relationship between Chart and State, and you can override OnModelCreating context to tell EF this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
        .HasMany(s => s.States)
        .WithMany();
}
```

Now something like this will work:

```
using (var context = new ChartContext())
{
    var state1 = new State { Name = "State1" };
    var state2 = new State { Name = "State2" };

    var chart =
        new Chart
        {
            Initial = state1,
            States = new List<State> { state1, state2 }
        };

    context.Charts.Add(chart);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, Chart now has an initial state and a collection of states, and the initial state is one of the collection of states.

If actually each State is associated with one and only Chart entity, then you'll need to figure out something else--there are probably workarounds to make this work, but not as easy to come up with as the solution above.